# FIRESTORE: Is there a work around for 'in' query for filtering data from a collection based on an array list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react application. I have a collection 'posts' from which I need to filter documents if these posts were made by users in a list like [user1, user2 ,...].

I can use the 'in' query and get the documents from the code below.
I get a total of 7 posts as expected.

```
db.collection('posts')
  .where('userId', 'in', [...friendList])
  .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    console.log('posts for home feed', snapshot);
    setPosts(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        post: doc.data(),
      }))
    );
  });
```

But it can only work if the length of [friendList] is upto 10. I tried to get the snapshots of posts made by each user using promises and iterate over this collected snapshot to get the documents (in posts variable) but I get all posts in the repeated over and over. The code I tried:

```
export default function Feed({ friendList }) {
  // currentUser context
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  // array to save posts from database
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  // function to fetch data from database
  useEffect(() => {
    getPostsFromFriendList(friendList);
  }, []);

  async function getPostsFromFriendList(friendList) {
    const promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < friendList.length; i++) {
      promises.push(getPosts(friendList[i]));
    }

    const postsForHomeFeed = await Promise.all(promises);
    const array = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < postsForHomeFeed.length; i++) {
      postsForHomeFeed[i].docs.map((doc) => {
        array.push({
          id: doc.id,
          post: doc.data(),
        });
      });
    }

    setPosts(array);

    console.log('posts for home feed', postsForHomeFeed);
  }

  function getPosts(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection('posts')
        // .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          resolve(snapshot);
        });
    });
  }
```

The console output trying to print the collected snapshots:[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hP1q.png)

The resulting array length of the combined snapshots is 3 as expected(friendList has 3 elements). Each of them is a firestore delegate. But each of these elements have a docs property of array length 26. The total documents in the post collection is 26. Why might this be happening?

I am sorry that I am rambling on and on. And thank you for reading my long question. I am grateful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is that you get all posts in `getPosts`. You would need to add the "where in" filter tehre to make it work:

```js
function getPosts(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.collection('posts')
      .where('userId', 'in', [userId])
        // .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          resolve(snapshot);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was commenting/uncommenting the code to see what works and totally ended up posting stale code. But using promises this way seem to work. I could not upvote because of my lack of reputation, but I have accepted the answer :)